# jQuery hover no longer working after executing script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's the setup I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/varMV.png

If I click on image B, it will switch image A and image B. If I click image E, it will switch image B and image E, and so on.

However, I want to add hover effects so that whenever I hover over an image, it will darken that image. I have that working already but when I click on (for example) image B, it will switch image B and image A but now image B is already dark and the hover effects will not work on image A anymore.

I'm using Wordpress:

```
 <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div class="content_wrapper">
            <div class="content_featured" style="float:left; "></div>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
                $i = 1;
            ?>
            <div class="content_children" style="float:right">
                <div class="content_left" style="float:left">
                <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                    static $count = 0;
                    if( $count == 5 ) { break; }

                    else {
                        if( $i == 1 ) {
                            ?><span><span class="main active"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><div style="background:black; margin:2px;"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></div></a></span></span><?php
                        } else {
                            ?><span class="child nonactive"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><div style="background:black; margin:2px;"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></div></a></span><?php
                        }
                        $i++;
                        $count++;
                    }
                ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="content_right" style="float:right;"></div>
            </div>

            <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
```

Here's the script so far:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
divide_content($);
cycle_images($);
darken_images($);

var main = jQuery(".content_left span:first").html();
jQuery(".content_left span:first").empty();
jQuery(".content_featured").append(main);
});

function cycle_images($) {
$(".nonactive").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).html();
    var b = $(".active").html();
    //alert(a+"\n\n"+b);
    $(this).empty();
    $(".active").empty();
    $(this).append(b);
    $(".active").append(a);
});
}

function divide_content($) {
var size = $(".content_left > span").size();
$(".content_left > span").each(function(index) {
    if(index >= size / 2) {
        $(this).appendTo(".content_right");
    }
});
}

function darken_images($) {
$(".nonactive img").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
});

$(".content_featured").hover(function() {
    $(".active img").fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    //alert("qwe");
}, function() {
    $(".active img").fadeTo(500, 1);
});
}
```

PS I know this is the wrong title but I don't know how else to state it.

EDIT:
Here's the best I could do with fiddle. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/83XYe/)

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for terrible presentation. EDIT: I'm not sure how to reproduce on fiddle..

Comment: Well put your html markup in the html section, add the scripts include the relevant libraries and run it, if it works click on share and post the link here.

Comment: I updated my post. But here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83XYe/) anyway